# Flask-SQLAlchemy data types

Tags: python, sql, types, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm starting to use the Flask-SQLAlchemy package in my web project and am wondering about the data type usage. It appears that the package can use any of the [SQL standard types](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#sql-standard-types), but also seems to have a few of it's own (`String`) that are likely recasts of one of the standard types. The notation difference to distinguish these seems to be caps (`INTEGER`) for the standard types and a starting cap (`Integer`) for the package specific types.

Does anyone know where they do an overview of all the permissible types - I'm mainly interested in understanding the package specific ones and their characteristics. I've been reading the documentation, and may have missed it. Otherwise, I know I can just keep it simple and use all standard types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html) page provides an overview of the types implemented in SQLAlchemy.

You can also use the `flask-sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy` class to look through the available data types.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right page of the documentation, you just need to skip up to the  [Column and Datatypes - Generic Types documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#generic-types).